# Is a lookup field required in a routers `detail_route`?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Looking over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions The example has `pk=None`:

```
@detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf])
def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
```

and says the following url pattern will be generated: `^users/{pk}/set_password/$`

Over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter It also says that `lookup` field is in the url: `{prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}/`

Does DRF pass the `lookup` value to the `detail_route` method? Based on the documentation, it looks like it does, but over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#example

If you scroll down to:

```
@detail_route()
    def group_names(self, request):
        """
        Returns a list of all the group names that the given
        user belongs to.
        """
        user = self.get_object()
        groups = user.groups.all()
        return Response([group.name for group in groups])
```

A lookup value is not asked for as an argument to the `group_names` function. My questions are:

1) Is `pk` / a lookup field argument required in a `detail_route`?

2) If not, then how does `self.get_object()` know which object to get?

3) Also, if not, then shouldn't `@list_route` be used instead since a lookup is not even being used?

Edit: Over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing It also says `The @detail_route decorator contains pk in its URL pattern and is intended for methods which require a single instance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is pk / a lookup field argument required in a detail_route?

Yes. Thanks for spotting it, it's fixed in the repository and will be updated next time the documentation will be generated.

> 2) If not, then how does self.get_object() know which object to get?

The view's arguments / keyword arguments is stored in the `view.args` and `view.kwargs` which get_object uses.

> 3) Also, if not, then shouldn't @list_route be used instead since a lookup is not even being used?

It's been used through self.get_object which returns the associated users so it's a detail_route.